# Gmail Backup with QNAP (TS-451U Pro) Retrieve domain user list from server fail

Tags: gmail, qnap

I am not able to add the accounts I have tried several users and no luck.  I get the same error.  I am able to ping [mail.google.com](http://mail.google.com) without any problems.

Images:

[Google OAuth2 Authorization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUpCb.png)

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbFbU.png)

I don't know what is the cause of that.

Comment: Be careful about sharing your credentials! It looks like your first image includes a username and a token that somebody else might use to access your data!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem on a TS251+ .
Removing gmail backup, then resintalling it solved the problem without losing configuration.
However, a side (?) effect I have is the system can't retrieve the domain user list anymore.
It's surprising but the engine beneath is gyb 0.20 as we are now on gyb 1.0. 0.20 i smore than 2 years old!
I'm considering installing 1.0 by hand.